# How to make a Wet/Dry or A/B mix control using Logic X (10.2.2) bus and mixer?

Tags: mixing, audio, mixer, logic-pro, logic

[image: logic workflow]

Here's what I have going in lieu of a wet/dry mix knob.

I'm using the pre-fader send and a submix bus to mix my clean and effected (outboard) signal.

I'd rather assign a single knob to handle each wet/dry submix. Having to pull two faders on my controller to mix wet and dry signal is not ideal.

For example: I should be able to go from 0 (100% Bus 1, or totally dry) to 64 (50% Bus 1 and 50% Bus 2 aka wet/outboard) to 127 (100% Bus 2) on a single knob or controller assignment.

There must be a more elegant solution. Any recommendations?

Comment: I may not be understanding fully, but can't you just use the mix/bypass on the EQ insert?

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm using a pre-fader send.

Potting up the EQ fader (Bus 1) mixes the clean signal in, but it's not proportional to the Wet side (Bus 2).

Basically, I need to operate the second fader (Bus 2) if I want more than 50% dry signal (If I want 75% dry and 25% wet I have to pot down bus 2).

It's no tragedy, but a simple wet/dry mix knob is a nice intuitive thing. Most plugins already have them, but Logic's I/O plugin does not (afaik).

I'm not looking for a simple on/off bypass which is very easy to accomplish.

Comment: I get that it's not what you're looking for, but could you use another EQ? I'm not a Logic user, so I can't really suggest anything else, sorry. For example MEqualizer (free from Melda Production, see [here](https://www.meldaproduction.com/MEqualizer)) has Wet/Dry mix, and is available as AU.

Comment: I suppose something could be rigged up in the environment or under controller assignments that maps fader 1 to 0-64 and fader 2 to 65-127, but I'd prefer a simpler solution.

Comment: I have plenty of plugins already that have mix knobs. I'm trying set up an equivalent for Logic's I/O plugin so I can do a wet/dry mix with my outboard gear.

Comment: Oh. It's outboard. Got it. Hope someone has an answer for you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured this out on my own:

**Quick and dirty:**
Assign the two faders you want to crossfade to the same control, then set the multiply in the advanced assignment settings (Command+L) to -1.01 and 1.00 for the two faders respectively.

**Nice:**
Get MRatio (http://www.meldaproduction.com/MRatio) and sidechain in the track you want to crossfade. Lots of control over curves, modulation, ratios, etc. This is what I'm doing.

Comment: you can set your question as answered

Comment: Blue Cat’s Gain Suite (free) is also nice. Similar effect without sidechaining. https://www.bluecataudio.com/Products/Product_GainSuite/